# Stepwise nested pattern mattching with exceptions

Tags: haskell, error-handling, pattern-matching

## Background

I'm building a lisp-like toy language in Haskell with the following (stripped down) AST:

```hs
type Lisp = ExceptT Error (StateT Env IO)
type PrimOp = [Value] -> Lisp Value
data Value
  -- | any identifier, e.g. "x", "lambda"
  = VName Name
  -- | s-expression, e.g. "(x y z)"
  | VExpr (NonEmpty Value)
  -- | curried lambda, e.g. "((lambda (x y) (y x)) 123)"
  --   or even simply "(lambda (x) x)"
  | VCurry (NonEmpty Name) Value Env
  -- | primitive / built-in syntactic operations, e.g. "lambda"
  | VPrimOp PrimOp
```

Part of the language is a primitive operation named `lambda`:

```lisp
(lambda (<args>...) <value>) -- syntax
(lambda (x y) x)             -- example: const function
```

... which gets translated to the following in Haskell AST:

```hs
VExpr (VName "lambda" :| [VExpr (VName "x" :| [VName "y"]), VName "x"])
```

... then evaluated by the primitive operation `primLambda`, converting it from a s-expression to a curried function:

```hs
VCurry ("x" :| ["y"]) (VName "x") <env> <- primlambda <above-ast>
```

## The Problematic Code

Due to various quirks of the language, I cannot write the `lambda` into the parser. Thus I have ended up with the following implementation of `lambda` as a `VPrimOp`:

```hs
primLambda :: PrimOp
primLambda values = do
  (params, result) <- case values of
    [params, result] -> pure (params, result)
    _ -> throwError $ EArgCount "lambda" 2 (length values)
  names <- case params of
    VExpr names -> pure names
    _ -> throwError $ EArgType "lambda" "VExpr" params
  names' <- forM names $ \case
    VName name -> pure name
    name -> throwError $ EArgType "lambda" "VName" name
  gets (VCont names' result)
```

Obviously there is a repeated pattern here: I'm doing some pattern matching at each of the 3 steps, and calling `throwError` if the pattern does not match. However, the second and third step looks only at part of the first result, and the third step has to match everything in a list. Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! By "_and throwing an error if the pattern does not match_" does that mean that the code is not working as expected?

Comment: @sᴀᴍ-onᴇᴌᴀ I meant "error" as in the code uses `throwError` as part of the `Lisp` monad stack, because the user gave the interpreter an invalid program. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tinkering around, I settled on this solution using [optics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics) and some type classes:

```
data Match a b  = a :& b
infixr 1 :&

type family MatchLength (o :: Type) :: Nat
type instance MatchLength () = 0
type instance MatchLength (Match a b) = 1 + MatchLength b

class MatchOptic o s a | o -> s, o -> a where
  matchOptic :: Text -> o -> s -> Lisp a

instance
  ( Is k An_AffineTraversal, Is k A_Review, Data s
  ) => MatchOptic (Optic' k i s a) s a where
  matchOptic name optic value = either throws pure (matching optic value) where
    throws _ = throwError (EArgType name
      (show (toConstr (review optic undefined)))
       (show (toConstr value)))

class MatchOptics o s r | o -> r where
  matchOptics :: Name -> o -> [s] -> Lisp r

instance MatchOptics () s () where
  matchOptics _ _ [] = pure ()
  matchOptics name _ values = throwError (EArgCount name 0 (length values))

instance
  ( KnownNat (MatchLength os), MatchOptic o s a, MatchOptics os s as
  ) => MatchOptics (Match o os) s (Match a as) where
  matchOptics name (optic :& optics) (value:values) = do
    result <- matchOptic name optic value
    results <- matchOptics name optics values `catchError` \case
      EArgCount n x y -> throwError (EArgCount n (x + 1) (y + 1))
      err -> throwError err
    pure (result :& results)
  matchOptics name optics [] = throwError (EArgCount name plen 0) where
    plen = fromIntegral (natVal (Proxy @(MatchLength os)))
```

`MatchOptic` matches a single `Value` with an optic (more specifically a `Prism`), and raises `EArgType` if the optic does not produce a match. It uses `Data` to automatically get the constructor of a value (e.g. `show (toConstr (Just 1)) == "Just"`).

`MatchOptics` matches a list of `[Value]` with multiple optics, and uses `:&` as a "polymorphic" list to store the `Optic`s and the matched results.

The resulting `primLambda` code looks like this:

```
primLambda :: PrimOp
primLambda values = do
  names :& result :& () <- matchOptics "lambda"
    (_VExpr :& simple @Value :& ()) values
  names' <- mapM (matchOptic "lambda" _VName) names
  gets (VCont names' result)
```

The code is much more concise and does length-matching and constructor-matching in one step. It also avoids the need to write many different `unpackX` functions like in @ShapeOfMatter's answer, since optics are automatically generated using template-haskell.

The solution can be extended by providing alternative `MatchOptic` instances. For example, the following instance and expression can be used to match aeson arrays that can also be null:

```
instance Is k A_Fold => MatchOptic (String, Optic' k i s a) s a where
  matchOptic name (cons, optic) value = maybe throws pure (headOf optic value)
    where throws = throwError (EArgType name cons "")

matchOptic "abc" ("optional array", failing 
  (_Null % to (const Nothing)) (_Array % to Just))
```

Comment: If you want a review of the updated code you need to add a follow up question rather than answering your own question. Since someone has already upvoted this answer, it is up to you to decide what you want.

Comment: This is the solution I'm satisfied with, so I'm not looking for a review of it.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of repeated code isn't large, I don't think that's worth worrying about. It does seem like you've got a lot of buried `case`s making your nice `do` block hard to read.

I don't think you can use `MonadFail` for this (although I'm sure you've got the instance on hand); I assume you want the rich custom errors you're making.

My first suggestion would be to move this logic to helpers that live with your `Error` class, something like

```hs
forceArgCount :: (MonadError Error m) => Int -> String -> [a] -> m [a]
forceArgCount neededLen label as = if neededLen == (length as)
                                   then pure as
                                   else throwError $ EArgCount label neededLen (length as)
...

primLambda values = do
  [params, result] <- forceArgCount 2 "lambda" values
  names <- unpackVExpr "lambda" params
  names' <- forM names (unpackVName "lambda")
  gets (VCont names' result)
```

This is unsatasfying in two ways:

- Pattern matching on a list of fixed size is runtime-failable.
  Also value-constants that describe the shape of a data-structure (*e.g.* `2`) are smelly.
  You could improve it (arguably) by using type-application to pass `neededLen` as a type-level Nat literal, and the return type would be a fixed-length vector with that length. (I was gonna crib together an example based on a project I did last year, but I'm not sure I should actually be recommending the libraries I was using. There are multiple options.)
- You'll have to write a different `unpackX` function for every use-case. It looks like the derivable class `Data.Data.Data` (in [base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data)) is supposed to help you write a more generic version (by letting you handle constructors as values); it's not something I've done.